# How to get a single Arabic letter in a string with its Unicode transformation value in DELPHI?

Tags: delphi

Considering this Arabic word(جبل) made of 3 letters .

-the first letter is   جـ,
-name is (ǧīm), 
-its Unicode value is FE9F when its in the beginning,
-its basic value is 062C and 
-its isolated value is FE9D but the last two values return the same shape drawing ج .

Now, Whenever I try to get it as a single character -trying many different ways-, Delphi returns the basic Unicode value.
well,that makes sense,but what happens to the char with transformation? It is a single char too..Looks like it takes the transformed value only when it is within a string, but where? how to extract it?When and which process decides these values?
Again the MAIN QUESTION:
**How can I get the Arabic letter or its Unicode value as it is within a string?**

*just for information: Unlike English which has tow cases for its letters(Capital and Small), Arabic has four cases(Isolated, Beginning,Middle And End) with different rules as well.*

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question. If you want to know how to write [U+FE9F](http://graphemica.com/%EF%BA%9F) in Delphi source code, in a modern Unicode version of Delphi. Do that simply like so:

```
Char($FE9F)
```

If you want to read individual characters from جبل then do it like this:

```
const
  MyWord = 'جبل';
var
  c: Char;
....
c := MyWord[1];//this is U+062C
```

Note that the code above is fine for your particular word because each code point can be encoded with a single UTF-16 `WideChar` character element. If the code point required multiple elements, then it would be best to transform to UTF-32 for code point level processing.

---

Now, let's look at the string that you included in the question. I downloaded this question using wget and the file that came down the wires was UTF-8 encoded. I used Notepad++ to convert to UTF16-LE and then picked out the three UTF-16 characters of your string. They are:

```
U+062C
U+0628
U+0644
```

You stated:

> The first letter is جـ, name is (ǧīm), its Unicode value is U+FE9F.

But that is simply incorrect. As can be seen from the above, the actual character you posted was U+062C. So the reason why your attempts to read the first character yield U+062C is that U+062C really is the first character of your string.

---

The bottom line is that nothing in your Delphi code is transforming your character. When you do:

```
S[1] := Char($FE9F);
```

the compiler performs a simple two byte copy. There is no context aware transformation that occurs. And likewise when reading `S[1]`.

---

Let's look at how these characters are displayed, using this simple code on a VCL forms application that contains a memo control:

```
Memo1.Clear;
Memo1.Lines.Add(StringOfChar(Char($FE9F), 2));
Memo1.Lines.Add(StringOfChar(Char($062C), 2));
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the rendering layer knows what to do with a U+062C character that appears at the beginning of the string.

Comment: IMHO, this is not the expected answer. The question is "how do we get U+FE9F instead of U+062C when reading the char value of the string"

Comment: @loursonwinny If you want a character to contain U+FE9F, then put U+FE9F into the char. But if the string contains U+062C that's because U+062C was placed there. There's no magic fairy that changes characters from one value to another. In other words, if you write `S[1] := Char($FE9F)` then you are safe to assert that `S[1]=Char($FE9F)`.

Comment: I don't think it is that easy when playing with unicode ;) I think that the OS reworks the string when it deals with arabic to finalize the ligatures

Comment: @loursonwinny Where does the OS come into play? I'm just talking about reading and writing elements of a Delphi string.

Comment: Do this test: Copy the first char of جبل in the clipboard (remember that the first char in an arabic word is the one at the right side) and paste it in an editor. the result is ج, which is the same letter but not the same glyph. The same happens when accessing MyWord[1]

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it's not happening in the Delphi code that accesses string elements. It's happening somewhere else.

Comment: In fact, you are right. The ligature certainly happens when drawing the string to the screen

Answer (score 1):

Shaping of Arabic characters for presentation in Windows is served by the Uniscribe services (USP10.dll). 
[UniScribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You may find the following blog post useful:
[Roozbeh's Programming Blog](http://delphi-ce.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/uniscribe-and-delphi.html)

Comment: Thanks for every one. I feel very close.Trying this:

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using string/char related methods. But using pchar, maybe can you access the memory and read the Pword values directly

EDIT: After discussing with David, I think that you will always get the basic/isolated value of the letter. The fact that begin or end glyph is used, is probably just handled by the display framework of the OS

Comment: It's simple enough to write some code that disproves what you say. Write a simple program that does `S[1]=Char($FE9F)` and then take a look at what happens in the debugger. It's a simple memory copy.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any IDE to play with where I am for the moment. Maybe tonight. But I believe what the OP said because I experienced it myself AFAIR

Comment: I believe what was said, but I also know that `S[i] := Char($FE9F)` will lead to `S[i]` having ordinal value of `$FE9F`. As I already said, it's a simple memory write that is isolated from the content of the string.

Comment: The compiler spits out `mov word ptr [eax],$fe9f`

Comment: Regarding your edit, I think that's right on the money. See the image in my latest edit. I'd upvote your answer if you got right of the factually incorrect first paragraph.